# MySQL BLOB Default Value

Tags: java, mysql

how to clear blob column cell in MySQL without remove complete row in the data table and what is the default value in MySQL blob data type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [11.4.3. The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html):

> BLOB and TEXT columns *cannot* have DEFAULT values.

Thus, if the column is NULLABLE then NULL is the default; otherwise there is no default value. (Although, at the application level, a blob of length=0 might be a sensible "default".)